# grep from a list with multiple fields

Tags: awk, grep

I would like to search a file "log.txt" using a source file with multiple fields "source.txt".

**Example of source file "source.txt":**

```
1.1.1.1,green
1.1.1.1,red
2.2.2.2,blue
```

**Example of file to be searched "log.txt"**

```
1.1.1.1,bla bla Yellow,30000,bla bla
1.1.1.1,bla bla,30000,bla bla green
1.1.1.1,bla red bla,30000,bla bla
2.2.2.2,bla bla,30001,bla red
2.2.2.2,Blue bla bla,30003,bla bla
```

**Desired output lists they keyword that triggered match followed by match such as:**

```
1.1.1.1,green:1.1.1.1,bla bla,30000,bla bla green
1.1.1.1,red:1.1.1.1,bla red bla,30000,bla bla
2.2.2.2,blue:2.2.2.2,Blue bla bla,30003,bla bla
```

Here is my attempt:

```
for i in `cat source.txt`    
do       
    echo $i:       
    grep -i $i log.txt     
done
```

So I was not able to print matching keywords at the beginning.

Comment: Have you attempted anything?  You can do this with `join` command.  `man join` is your friend.

Comment: `I didn't want to muddy up waters with my grep attempt`. Looks like you think we're a free coding service...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below [awk](/questions/tagged/awk) will give you desired output as requested above.

```
awk -F, '
         FNR==NR{
                  a[$1]=$1 in a ? a[$1]","$2:$2;
                  next
                }
         $1 in a{
                  split(a[$1],c); 
                  for(i=1; i in c; i++)
                  { 
                      if(match(tolower($0),c[i]))
                      { 
                         print $1 FS c[i] ":" $0; 
                         next
                      }  
                   }
                }
        ' source log
```

**Input**

```
$ cat source 
1.1.1.1,green
1.1.1.1,red
2.2.2.2,blue

$ cat log 
1.1.1.1,bla bla Yellow,30000,bla bla
1.1.1.1,bla bla,30000,bla bla green
1.1.1.1,bla red bla,30000,bla bla
2.2.2.2,bla bla,30001,bla red
2.2.2.2,Blue bla bla,30003,bla bla
```

**Output**

```
$ awk -F, '
         FNR==NR{
                  a[$1]=$1 in a ? a[$1]","$2:$2;
                  next
                }
         $1 in a{
                  split(a[$1],c); 
                  for(i=1; i in c; i++)
                  { 
                      if(match(tolower($0),c[i]))
                      { 
                         print $1 FS c[i] ":" $0; 
                         next
                      }  
                   }
                }
        ' source log 
1.1.1.1,green:1.1.1.1,bla bla,30000,bla bla green
1.1.1.1,red:1.1.1.1,bla red bla,30000,bla bla
2.2.2.2,blue:2.2.2.2,Blue bla bla,30003,bla bla
```